# Excel - How to get last the average of the last 10 values in a row which consist of a random mix of numbers and "N/A"

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, array-formulas

So i have a row of numbers which is consistently added to, which may be like `4,N/A,N/A,5,5,6,7,4,N/A,N/A,N/A,5,N/A` and I need a formula which is able to calculate the average of the last 10 numbers in the row.

I have tried

```
=AVERAGE(OFFSET(C7,0,COUNT(C7:X7)-MIN(10,COUNT(C7:X7)),1,MIN(10,COUNT(C7:X7))))
```

Comment: "I have tried" - with what result?

Comment: I assume you want to ignore the "N/A", are these actual error `#N/A` or a text string?

Comment: What happens if there is less than 10 numbers, like your example.

Comment: The N/A are text strings that the user inputs. If its less than 10 it's okay to just average those values. Say if it's 7 just average the 7 numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(1:1,AGGREGATE(14,7,COLUMN(1:1)/(ISNUMBER(1:1)),MIN(10,COUNT(1:1)))):INDEX(1:1,AGGREGATE(14,7,COLUMN(1:1)/(ISNUMBER(1:1)),1)))
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: It works!! Thank you so much! Just a small issue, it returns only 8 cells with numbers if my data set starts in column C instead of column A. How do i adjust the formula to make it work?